# Вопрос про mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod_rewrite, php

Здравствуйте. Есть вопрос по `mod_rewrite`'у. Как можно из такого `URL`  `mysite.ru/index.php?title=auto` сделать `mysite.ru/auto/` . Можно ли будет использовать русские буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Правило для главной страницы
RewriteRule ^\/?$ public/index.php?title=default [L,QSA]

#Правило для остальных страниц
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?$ public/index.php?title=auto [L,QSA]
```

К сожалению, с русскими буквами такая магия не прокатит (во всяком случае тривиальным кодом так точно), но нам никто не мешает передавать русские значения GET'ом ( в правилах это реализуется с помощью флага QSA ).

Для примера передачи полностью русских GET параметров - напишем простой PHP код:

```
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); // мы не хотим крякозябров
  if(!empty($_GET['язык'])) { echo 'Вы выбрали ' . $_GET['язык'] . ' язык'; }
```

Естественно этот код разместим в index.php, введем в URL например mysite.ru/?язык=русский
И увидим что все прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?title=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

если конкретно для этого адреса, то как-то так

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^auto/$ index.php?title=auto
```